# How to get contact's photo from exchange?

Tags: java, exchange-server, webdav, exchange-server-2007

How can I get from `microsoft exchange 2003`  contact photo using `WebDAV`?

Answer (score 0):

There is WebDAV protocol Java API for Exchange server 2003 and 2007. It is called "JWebDAV for Exchange". It should be possible to get contact's photo.

Comment: Yeach, I know bout it. My problem is that I can't get photo using this protocol. I'm able to get other contact information but can't find the way how to get photo.

Answer (score 0):

In Exchange 2003, the contact photo is an Active Directory attribute, and not in Exchange.  This didn't change until Exchange Server 2010.

Attribute:

```
thumbnailphoto
```

Exchange 2007 is tagged in the question, perhaps there's a way to get this attribute via WebDAV there. However I would highly doubt the attribute is exposed via Exchange 2003.

Source: [technet blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ilvancri/archive/2010/01/08/follow-up-import-recipientdataproperty.aspx)

This truly doesn't answer the WebDAV portion of your question, but hopefully puts you on the appropriate path with regard to the location of the pictures.

---

I found [an article](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2009/12/using-contact-photo-in-ews-in-exchange.html) detailing using Exchange Web Services to manage user contact photos on Exchange 2010.  EWS simply won't do what you want if you're on Exchange 2003 (web services were introduced with Exchange 2007).

[MS Technet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900502(v=exchg.150).aspx) article on using the current function to request what you want. It appears this was introduced in Exchange 2013.

I have a bad feeling you're going to end up doing MAPI calls if you want to grab this info from an Exchange 2003 service.

Comment: You are right from one side, this is possible that photo is getting from the Active Directory, but what about contacts who are not in your domain, which are created directly in the outlook contacts folder?